# File Input type does not show file name using Jquery File Upload

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

Does anyone see an error or could help me how to debug in this piece of code the reason why when I select a image in my input always show me "no file selected" msg. Everything works but for the DOM is like no file were selected in that moment so I can´t validate that input. Thanks in advance.

the Html part:

```
    <span id="freeInputFile" class="btn btn-success fileinput-button-creator">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span>Add files...</span>
        <input id="freeRoomInputV2" type="file" name="filesFree" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg"/>
    </span>
    <br />
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="filesFree" class="files"></div>
    </div>
```

the javascript part (using query file upload): If help: the button was appended in different tag of preview thumbnail img.

```
 $(function () {
     'use strict';
      var urlv2 = ROOT_PATH+'/uploader/',
    uploadButtonv2 = $('<button/>')
        .addClass('btn btn-primary beButtonFormat create_free_room')
        .prop('disabled', true)
        .text('Processing...')
        .on('click', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data();
            $this
                .off('click')
                .text('Abort')
                .on('click', function () {
                    $this.remove();
                    data.abort();
                });
            data.submit().always(function () {
                $this.remove();
            });
        });
$('#freeRoomInputV2').fileupload({
    url: urlv2,
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 100,
    previewMaxHeight: 100,
    previewCrop: true
})
.on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {

})
.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    $("#filesFree").empty();
    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#filesFree');
    data.context2 = $('<div/>').appendTo('#upload_button_free');

    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
                .append($('<span/>').text(file.name)),
            node2 = uploadButtonv2.clone(true).data(data);
        if (!index) {
            node
                .append('<br>');
        }
        node.appendTo(data.context);
        node2.appendTo(data.context2);
    });
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context2.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {


}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .append('<br>')
            .append(error);
    });
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery File Upload [manual](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-doesnt-the-file-input-field-show-the-path-of-a-selected-file) default behavior is to replace the input . you could avoid the input replacement with replaceFileInput so it will maintain the regular behavior.